# Can I insert text from another file into my cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have this for example in my template:

```
 ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: MyApi
        Description: My AWS API Gateway config
        Body:
          # INSERT swagger.yml content here
```

Is there some cloudformation function I can use to read swagger.yml in or attach it under "Body:"? So I can keep it in another file and my template doesn't become huge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [Fn::Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html) function that allows you to call different Cloudformation macros to process your templates. One of those macros is [AWS::Include](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html)

Heres an example:

```
Resources:
  APIGateway:
    Fn::Transform:
      Name: AWS::Include
      Parameters:
        Location:
          Fn::Sub: s3://partials-bucket/${PartialsEnv}/resources/api-gateway.yaml
```

Here `api-gateway.yaml` will have the full definition of your resource.

You can use this function in the same way as other intrinsic functions. The only caveat is `AWS::Include` will only work with files hosted in S3 so you'll need to upload your partials separatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `BodyS3Location` .

> The Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) location that points to
>   an OpenAPI file, which defines a set of RESTful APIs in JSON or YAML
>   format.

For Example

```
"BodyS3Location": {
          "Bucket": "you_bucket_name",
          "Key": "filename.yaml"
        }
```

For more see  [BodyS3Location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-bodys3location)